# Transform a Google Spreadsheet table? Columns by rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I need to transform this table

[image]
into this one, with de Services columns as rows:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A2&"|"&B2&"|"&TRANSPOSE($C$1:$E$1)&"|"&C2:E2),"|");
               SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A3&"|"&B3&"|"&TRANSPOSE($C$1:$E$1)&"|"&C3:E3),"|");
               SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A4&"|"&B4&"|"&TRANSPOSE($C$1:$E$1)&"|"&C4:E4),"|");
               SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(A5&"|"&B5&"|"&TRANSPOSE($C$1:$E$1)&"|"&C5:E5),"|")})
```

**here is the spreadsheet:** **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y-BcSPpJgcw6eUYWt7OVEEsXhWCjSa7mEyqbdxjgHec/edit?usp=sharing)**

[image]