# Displaying specific column header for cells, based on the cell value and its row header

Tags: google-sheets, google-workspace

I have a very large table looking somewhat along the lines of the below example:

```
        Date1   Date2   Date3   Date4   Date5
        ShiftA  ShiftB  ShiftA  ShiftB  ShiftA
Person1 x       x       x       x       late
Person2 late    x       late    late    x
Person3 late    late    x       x       x
```

I'd like to find some way of displaying a list of the dates on which an individual was "late" to a certain shift type.

Using two input values, for example "Person2" and "ShiftA", it would yield an output "Date1", "Date3" (optimally the output would be in the form of a row with one cell for each date, but that's not necessarily within the scope of this question).

I've tried using things like nested `filter()` functions, `query()` functions and `index()` functions containing `match()`, but I keep running into different issues and I feel like I'm not quite savvy enough at Google Sheets to find a great solution to my problem.

Any push in the right direction would also be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The shape of your data makes harder to get the result that you are looking for. The first step in the "right direction", is to transform the data into a simple table structure like the following:

```
|   Person    |   Date   |   Shift  |   Value    |
+-------------+----------+----------+------------+
|   Person 1  |   Date1  |  ShiftA  |     X      |
|   Person 1  |   Date1  |  ShiftB  |   late     |
```

Once your data is transformed into the above shape it will be more easy to get

> a list of the dates on which an individual was "late" to a certain shift type

You could use FILTER, QUERY, a Pivot Table, etc.

Related questions in this site

- [Transpose Ranges repeated by row](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115804/88163)
- [Transform a Google Spreadsheet table? Columns by rows](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/119603/88163)

Related question in Stack Overflow

- [Unpivot in Google Sheets - multipe header columns and rows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36112210/1595451)

Other related in Stack Overflow

- [How do you create a “reverse pivot” in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24954722/1595451)
- [Formula to array all columns with first column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43060844/1595451)